# Finding values in a list of key/value pairs

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists

```
old_name_list = [a-1234, a-1235, a-1236]
new_name_list = [(a-1235, a-5321), (a-1236, a-6321), (a-1234, a-4321), ... ]
```

I want to search recursively if the elements in old_name_list exist in new_name_list and returns the associated value with it, for eg. the first element in old_name_list returns `a-4321`, second element returns `a-5321`, and so on until old_name_list finishes.

I have tried the following and it doesn't work

```
for old_name, new_name in zip(old_name_list, new_name_list):
    if old_name in new_name[0]:
        print new_name[1]
```

Is the method I am doing wrong or I have to make some minor changes to it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: zipping `old_name_list` and `new_name_list` makes no sense - that way you're ONLY checking whether the first element of `old_name_list` matches the first pair of `new_name_list`, etc.

Comment: Try printing the result of `zip(old_name_list, new_name_list)` and look at what you get.  In Python 3.x you will need to use `list()` to explicitly force it out into a list so you can look at it, but in Python 2.x `zip()` gives you a list.  When you look at the list, you will see why your program doesn't work correctly.  `zip()` pairs up one element from each list, in strict order, so the `in` test will rarely succeed.  By the way, rather than `in` you should just use `==` to see if two strings are equal.

Comment: Nothing in this problem requires recursion. Perhaps the word you were looking for was "repeatedly".

Comment: I edited the title to get rid of the word "recursively".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build a `dict()` based on your second list, and lookup in that.

```
old_name_list = ["a-1234", "a-1235", "a-1236"]
new_name_list = [("a-1235", "a-5321"), ("a-1236", "a-6321"), ("a-1234", "a-4321") ]

d = dict(new_name_list)

for n in old_name_list:
    print d[n]
```

You do need to put quotes around strings like "a-1234".

Comment: You can even use `d.get(n)` in case `n` is not an existing value to avoid `KeyError`.

Comment: @Emmanuel: yes, a good idea.  Or just use `if n in d:` before the `print`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
found_items = [item[1] for item in new_name_list if item[0] in old_name_list]
```

Comment: Looking up an entry in a list is O(n) where n is the length of the list.  This will at least be using the C code inside Python to do it, instead of an explicit Python loop, but it will still be much faster for big lists to build a `dict()` and use the O(1) lookup.  For short lists, this is as good as anything and might be faster than building the `dict()`.

Comment: @steveha: although this is theoretically true, in the practice this solution will be just as fast as any other.

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary may be the best way to do this.

```
old_name_list = ['a-1234', 'a-1235', 'a-1236']
new_name_list = [('a-1235', 'a-5321'), ('a-1236', 'a-6321'), ('a-1234, a-4321')]
mapping = dict(new_name_list)
values = [mapping[item] if item in mapping for item in old_name_list]
print values
```